# git rebase skips some commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

Have a git repo with this history (**initial repo**):

```
A-B---C---D-H-I
   \     /
    E-F-G
```

Want to change history to:

```
    I`(will squash all from B till I) 
   /
  A-B
     \
      E-F-G
```

But when I tried `rebase -i <SHA "A">` from `G`, `D` is absent from the list of commits available, I see:

```
pick B
pick C
pick E
pick F
pick G
pick H
pick I
```

If I remove commits from the of shoot branch `E-F-G` and save order to rebase as:

```
pick B
squash C
squash H
squash I
```

again I lost changes from commit "D"

I decided problem by `git reset --soft <SHA "A">` and after `commit`

**Question** But I wonder why git did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D` is a merge commit so there are no changes in it so there is nothing to keep from it (unless there were merge conflict resolution captured).  If you want to confirm do `git show <D hash>` and it should show you that nothing is changing (or the conflict resolutions).

Because you are rebasing this commit is no longer going to have any reason to exist so it disappears.

The next time you do this operation I would strongly suggest you do the following, which I do whenever I'm rebasing or squashing.... **Note that this assumes and is only true for when you are only rebasing to squash commits or reorder history and not if you are editing/ammending anything**

`git diff <resulting branch> <original_branch|original_hash|origin/my_original_branch>`  This way we can see that nothing changes except commit history/commit messages, that no content changed.

Comment: :) In my case not exactly, because I can make "amend" after :(
diff --cc OtusHW/Assets/Game/Assets/Model/Dwarf/Player.prefab.meta
index 0000000,b618b21..366d8b4
mode 000000,100644..100644
--- a/OtusHW/Assets/Game/Assets/Model/Dwarf/Player.prefab.meta
+++ b/OtusHW/Assets/Game/Assets/Model/Dwarf/Player.prefab.meta
@@@ -1,0 -1,7 +1,11 @@@
+ fileFormatVersion: 2
++<<<<<<<< HEAD:OtusHW/....Model/Dwarf/Dwarf.prefab.meta
++guid: a617d0f313990bc4c837d58c48661e36
++========
+ guid: 08e1a515f982cec41a667ad752dce00c
++>>>>>>>> AOD_FSM_Animations:OtusHW/.../Model/Dwarf/Player.prefab.meta

Comment: the diff assumes that you didn't make other changes, are you saying you amended as part of the squash and made changes or that this diff showed you a resulting difference that isn't expected?

Comment: And did exist the simple method to remove from the initial repo not demanded part of merged branch "E-F-G" without rebase and create additional commits (by idea the commit "C" & "D" are summarized the all changes after "A")?

Comment: will put into answer

Comment: so i thought i had a solution for you but C broke my solution.. someone else might have an answer to it but I cant think of a way to do it without rebasing... unless you did some cherry picking ... you could do that...  create a new branch from commit C and then `git cherry pick H..I`

Comment: you should really make that second thing a seperate question and i should move my answer there :-) but I'm heading offline for dinner now. I'll check in later. cheers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77115895/git-is-possible-to-remove-merged-commits-from-repository-without-rebase

Comment: FYI I added separated Question related to part2 (as you proposed) of my initial question, therefore your response "Part2" linked to nothing