# git is possible to remove merged commits from repository without rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

Have a git repo with this history (**initial repo**):

```
A-B---C---D-H-I
   \     /
    E-F-G
```

Want to change history to:

```
A-B---C---H-I
```

Did exist the simple method to remove from the **initial repo** not demanded part of merged branch "E-F-G" without rebase and create additional commits (by idea the commit "C" & "D" are summarized the all changes after "A")?

Note that this is a corollary of the main question asked here: [git rebase skips some commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77115801/git-rebase-skips-some-commits)

Comment: It looks like `D` is a merge commit, but you still show it in your desired state. If you removed the merged branch, you would end up with `A-B-C-H'-I'`, where `H` and `I` would be transformed into `H'` and `I'` because their history has changed. You cannot change the history of your repository without creating new commits.

Comment: This situation looks like undo merge commit, right?

Comment: If your team works within more than one branch, you have to use `rebase` in order your merges to be fast-forward, ie without redundant three-way merge commits.

Comment: Even without rebase, you cannot do that without rewriting history, i.e. (re)creating the commits as new commits. You cannot continue using the existing commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `E-F-G` from the history as if they had never happened and make history instead be `A-B-H'-I'` Then you have two options.. the first you know, it's the manual big rebase thing.  You could have considered using `git revert D` but that wouldn't remove them from the history it would just negate them. ( and you seem to want them out of the history )

The other option and best thing I an think of for you is

`git checkout C -b new_history && git cherry-pick I..H && git checkout whatever && git reset --hard new_history && git push --force-with-lease`

This will create a new brach `new_history` from commit `C` and then cherry pick I and H onto it.  Then you can do a `git rebase -i A` so that you can squash the commits down as you like.  Finally you check out whatever original branch you had, do a hard reset to the contents of `new_history` and `force push` it so that it overrides the remote version to delete the history you don't want ( assuming you want to completely destroy that history )

Answer (score 0):

> Did exist the simple method to remove from the initial repo not demanded part of merged branch?

You have to use `rebase` for your MRs to be fast-forward, ie without redundant three-way merge commits.
So, if you know what you are doing (hard reset is awaiting) you can try following steps (i would recommend to train on a copy of your target branch before).

1. Save your `H-I` commits in a separate branch before running (being currently in your target `main` branch):

   `git branch post-merge-history`
2. Just cut off your target `main` branch to `C` commit.

   `git reset --hard C`
3. Squash commits into single one in your `topic` branch (`E-F-G` commits) and rebase it.

   `git checkout topic && git reset --soft E && git commit -m "D-Prime"`

   `git rebase main`

   `git checkout main && git merge topic` //it would be fast-forward
4. Cherry pick those post-merge `H-I` commits.

   `git cherry-pick H I`
5. If all is okay, these temporal branches can be removed:

   `git branch -D topic post-merge-history`
6. Finally share recently reconstructed main branch:

   `git push --force`

History should look like this:

```
A - B - C - D`- H - I
```

**PS**: Probably you might replace rebase & merge on step 3 with cherry pick of `D-Prime` commit.
It should work.

I didn't test these steps but they look like it makes sense.
Cheers!

Comment: That whole mess is convoluted unnecessary and could have been replaced with a single `git rebase -i` in which you squash what you want.  It doesn't even accomplish the main goal of this question.

Comment: OP asked to reconstruct without rebase, see PS section, btw. Basically these are 4 steps.

Comment: but you rebased in step 3 so that defeats the purpose of not rebasing